# Keeping data between sessions without using get, post or cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one controller class with two action functions.  One action is my login page with one view, and the other is my backend page with multiple views.

```
public ActionResult Login(...)
{
    if (logged in or login success)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Backend","Controller");
    }
    ...
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Backend(...)
{
    if(session expired or not logged in)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login","Controller");
    }
    ...
    return View("someView");
}
```

The issue is when the backend action has to send the user to the login action and I want to show the user a message like "Session expired" on the login page.

As an example ViewBag only lives in the current session. But is there a similar and easy way to store information between sessions?  So I can set a message in the backend, then redirect to login, and have the login read that message and display it in the view?  Kinda like PersistentViewBag.

I really do not want to use get, post or cookies, as is a viable option but then I rather just have the login as its own view in the backend action instead.

Comment: you say the issue is **I want to show the user a message like "Session expired" on the login page**, but then go on to explain unrelated issues like ViewBag persistence. So, I'm a little confused if this IS your issue or just related

Comment: @Dave A: Unrelated it is not. You can use ViewBag to display a message in any view in the current session. Using a little imagination a persistent ViewBag could be used to display a message in views across sessions. Almost like a server side cookie.

Comment: I think there are misunderstandings: **As an example ViewBag only lives in the current session**. Not true. ViewBag is a member of Controller and shares it's scope. You could lose Session and retain ViewBag, vice-versa. I feel like there are many issues / concerns being posted. Is you issue primarily **to show the user a message like "Session expired" on the login page**? If so, I have an answer. If not, I'm struggling to completely understand the question.

Comment: @Dave A: Yes my issue is primarily to show the user a message. But as RedirectToAction does nothing more than sending a 302 to the browser, I don't see how it can retain a variable between those sessions...?

Comment: If that is your issue, you can create an Action Filter that redirects the user to Login screen with a specific message like **I want to show the user a message like "Session expired" on the login page**. I have created them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the querystring for passing data when you are redirecting to the login page.

```
public ActionResult Backend(...)
{
    if(session expired or not logged in)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login","Controller",new { IsSessionExpired = true });
    }
    ...
    return View("someView");
}
```

In your Login action you can check the querystring and decide if you want to display the message.

**Update**

You can also use TempData if you do not want to use the querystring.

```
public ActionResult Backend(...)
{
    if(session expired or not logged in)
    {
        TempData["IsSessionExpired"] = true;
        return RedirectToAction("Login","Controller");
    }
    ...
    return View("someView");
}
```

Then you can check it in Login action:

```
if(TempData["IsSessionExpired"] != null)
{
    //Show message
}
```

Comment: But this is using get request, isn't it? Nothing wrong with that, but anyone can potentially put whatever they want into a get request. And even though it's only a message, and one needs to know the keyword, I would like to not use get requests and simply keep it server side - if possible.

Comment: Thanx! That was so simple. Reading a bit about TempData and that is what I want :-)